# Getting only a single record out of many the first time kafka consumer gets a record?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka and spring-kafka-test versions 1.0.2.RELEASE.

In one of my tests, my application sends 100 records in a row to a single TopicPartion on an EmbeddedKafka instance using the KafkaTemplate and mostly default config settings.

I use the KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(consumer) method to try to get the records from the Kafka instance and verify that they have all been sent.

The first time I call getRecords, I only receive a single record. If I call it again, I get the other 99.

If I explicitly set the consumer's position to the beginning of the TopicPartition and then call getRecords, I get all 100.

Why would getRecords only get a single record the first time? Is there some better way to get all 100 at once then by explicitly calling seekToBeginning on the consumer?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a timing issue. It's quite possible that only one message was available the first time you called `poll()` - that method makes no guarantees as to how many messages will be fetched. When you write code you shouldn't assume that you will receive X records at a go. There is a consumer property from Kafka 0.10 `max.poll.records` that for test purposes you may want to set to 1, and then perform a receive loop until you have polled all 100.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely just a race condition - the consumer is sitting in `poll()` and the broker sends the first message as soon as it arrives.

See properties `fetch.min.bytes` and `fetch.max.wait.ms` in the [kafka docs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#newconsumerconfigs).

`fetch.min.bytes` is 1 by default.

**EDIT**

You could also try `flush()` ing the `KafkaTemplate` before calling `getRecords()`.

However, your test should not really rely on getting all the messages in one fetch - too brittle.

Comment: The same thing happens if I flush the `KafkaTemplate` then wait 5 seconds before calling `getRecords()`. Increasing the value of `fetch.min.bytes does` increase the total number of records returned by the first call to `getRecords`. I would expect 5 seconds to be plenty of time for the messages to all make it to the broker. The next ~80 messages are all available to the next `getRecords` call made immediately following the first. Is there anything else that can be done to guarantee all the messages are there before the consumer reads or that the consumer will read all messages available?

Comment: I am a little surprised the `flush()` didn't help, but as I said in my last edit - your test will be brittle if you rely on timing alone, so a large enough `fetch.min.bytes` with a large `fetch.max.wait.ms` is probably the only way to get a reliable test. It will make your test run longer (unless you can figure out exactly how many bytes 100 messages - with overhead - is in bytes) but it will be reliable (until kafka changes the size of the overhead :) ).

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to leave that wait in there. I was just trying to test whether the problem was whether the messages were still in flight to Kafka or not. It seems like when the consumer is called the first time, all the messages should be there already. But, the first time, the consumer seems to only be reading enough messages to satisfy the `fetch.min.bytes` value, then on the second call it will read as many other messages as are available regardless of size. Why is the first call dependent on the `fetch.min.bytes` value but the second isn't?

Comment: I don't know - that's a question for the kafka guys. Probably just the way their internal algorithms work.